# How do I set up a QPainter window when logical coordinates are small and fractional?

Tags: qt, coordinates, coordinate-transformation

I want to render a scene on a QWidget, and I need to define a transofrmation from world coordinates to screen coordinates. [QPainter::setWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpainter.html#setWindow) seems to be the correct function to use but it defines its logical coordinates as `int`, not `float`.

My logical coordinates are not only floating-point, they are also very small. The window of logical coordinates is something like `(1.5,1.5)..(1.54,1.53)`.

I can't use `setWindow` because the rouding errors utterly destroy my coordinates, so how do I set up a `QPainter` transformation such that rendering the rectangle `(x,y)..(x+width,y+height)` will exactly fill the widget, when the rectangle has arbitrary floating-point values?

(The rectangle has already been chosen to have the correct aspect ratio to fit the widget.)

Comment: Is there any reason you can perform another simple transformation?  That is, rather than specifying a logical coordinate as 1.54 "things" could it instead be 1540 milli-"things"?

Comment: a) the widget is for zooming in, b) transformations are not integer-based in general

Answer (score 5):

You could probably write your own "floating point" version of `QPainter::setWindow`...

```
void set_painter_window (QPainter &painter, const QRectF &logical_rect)
{
  QTransform xform;
  xform.scale(painter.viewport().width() / logical_rect.width(),
              painter.viewport().height() / logical_rect.height());
  xform.translate(-logical_rect.left(), -logical_rect.top());
  painter.setTransform(xform);
}
```

Appears to work as expected in the few simple tests I've cobbled together.